# has_many through and polymorphic relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many, has-many-through, has-many-polymorphs

I don't know if this is possible, but here goes:

```
FruitBasket
  has_many :apples
  has_many :bananas
  ######## What to put here to access Worm through its pest_holder relationship?
Apple
  has_many :worms, :as => :pest_holder
  belongs_to :fruit_basket
Banana
  has_many :worms, :as => :pest_holder
  belongs_to :fruit_basket
Worm
  belongs_to :pest_holder, :polymorphic => true
```

What is the relationship I need to be able to call:

```
red_delicious = Apple.first
red_delicious.worms.whatever
```

And have it grab all of the Worm's through Apple's and Banana's polymorphic relationship with Worm?

It seems kind of backwards, but I appreciate the help anyway! If there's any clarification needed, just ask.

Comment: These questions are **SOOOOOO** much harder to answer with fake model names.

Comment: Yeah...sorry about that. (-;
Thanks for the edit, though!

Comment: Ok, so now your sample code is confusing, did you mean to have `FruitBasket` in there somewhere?

Comment: I think he means to be able to grab the fruit_basket through a worm, and grab the worms of a given fruit_basket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Guessing the answer to my own comment above)

You can't do what you want to, there's no Rails helper to allow you to join through to `Worm` from `FruitBasket` in a single association.  You can have `apple_worms` and `banana_worms` but I'm sure you guessed that already, and that that's not what you want.

What you'll need to do is to create your own method to get to the correct `Worm`s - something like this:

```
def worms
  Worm.where :id => apple_ids + banana_ids
end
```

Comment: Yeah, I was curious if there was a helper to let me do something like that but apparently not.

Comment: It might be nice if `:through => [ :apples, :bananas ]` worked.